# Application specific data for the MySQL slow query log?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, logging

I've a slow query log from MySQL on one side and a big PHP application on the other side littered with `mysql_query()` statements. I'm searching for a better solution to find the slow queries from the log in the PHP application code other than intelligently grep'ing the source code.

My idea is that it might be possible to enrich the SQL queries with some meta information i.e. the file name and the line number where the `mysql_query()` is called. But I can't find anything targeting this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at

http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php

And comment from there:

```
rename_function('strlen', 'new_strlen');
override_function('strlen', '$string', 'return override_strlen($string);');

function override_strlen($string){
        return new_strlen($string); 
}
```

But I suggest you, to use any ORM, over your queries.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'll go that route, but instead of using APD (last release around 2004, not maintained anymore), I try the same with the [uopz extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.uopz.php) or the [runkit extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php).

Answer (score 0):

Comments *might* be propagated to the SlowLog:

```
$sql = '/* ' . __FILE__ . ':' . __LINE__ . ' */ ' . 
    "SELECT ... ";
```

(This technique may be off, depending on what version of MySQL/MariaDB you are using.)